# Doctrine 2: does it automatically cache? If so, how to clear it?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I've been having some strange issues with Doctrine 2, and I was wondering if there is some default cache that I can clear?  Thanks for any help you might be able to provide!

Comment: No, it does not automatically cache (must be setup: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/caching.html).  What problems are you having that you think a cache is causing?

Comment: @Corbin, I'm using STI, with a base User class, and 3 subclasses (Contractor, Client, and Internal).  I have another event entity with a many to one relationship to a contractor entity.  When I retrieve this event entity, for some reason, it contains an internal user proxy, instead of a contractor user proxy, which leads to a fatal error since it cannot find an internal user with the given user id.  I have no idea why this would happen, and it only happens in my production environment...works fine on my local wamp, and i'm just about out of ideas :(

Comment: Hmmm...  Is the object completely wrong (wrong database row basically) or is the right data just in the wrong kind of object?  The odd part to me is that it would happen in production but not development.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add, it ONLY happens with a specific contractor id.  So if an event has a FK linking to this specific contractor, then for some reason doctrine uses the internal user proxy.  If an event has a FK linking to any OTHER contractor, it uses the proper contractor proxy.  Also, it's the exact right data, just in the wrong proxy object.  I checked the discriminator column for that user and it is for sure set to contractor.

Comment: If it's just one record being hydrated into the wrong type of object, that is quite an odd issue.  Have you double checked the discriminator column?  Maybe made sure there's not a row with the same name who is an Internal?  I just can't imagine a bug in either your code or Doctrine's that would have such an odd effect...  Hmm....

Comment: Yeah i checked the discriminator column many times.  It just has the wrong Proxy object for some reason, and I just don't have a clue as to why it would behave this way

Comment: Hmm, I really can't imagine anything that would be causing it then that isn't a very subtle bug.  I guess you could trace backwards through the hydration and figure out at what point it decides it's the wrong object, and why.